# Ui grid check if any row selected?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid and a button, When i click on button it should first check if at-least one row is selected and show alert on if not.
I tried

```
gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows()
```

but its returning nothing, and I am not able to put any if-else check.
(i don't want to use noUnselect)
Can anybody help..?

Comment: Could you post your code? How is gridApi defined?

Answer (score 1):

Try to place your code inside onRegisterApi:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
              [...]
                onRegisterApi : function (gridApi) {
                    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                    $log.debug(gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows() );
                    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
                 $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
                    $log.debug(gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows() );
                }
            };
```

Comment: Like Rob says, you need to save the gridApi in onRegisterApi - either to the $scope or another local object- if you are using controllerAs syntax vm then vm.gridApi. Then you can use elsewhere in your controller/service: var selectedRows = vm.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length);
```

it gives no.of rows selected..

```
if(gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length ==0)
```

no row is selected...